# What portion of all possible turing machines halt?

Tags: turing-machines, halting-problem, turing-completeness

Has anyone estimated [Chaitin's constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chaitin's_constant) for Turing machines with an empty tape as input?

Comment: The title has nothing to do with the body of your question. "Portion" doesn't make sense for infinite sets.

Comment: This is indeed a very different question from the one in the title. You can either talk about asymptotic density, or about actual counting up to some length (this is the "Chatin's constant estimation" part). The question about density has a good answer here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73187/density-of-halting-turing-machines